What's the simplest deep learning approach in signal processing? A 1D CNN?
I have a three datasets each containing one signal of a specific type (normal, periodically jammed, constantly jammed). I would like to experiment with this dataset to predict wether a signal is normal or if being jammed, the type. Fot this experimentation I thought about CNN but I read that they work better with 2D data and images. What would you recommend?
EDit: It is a time series.

What is the data type, vector or time-series/sequence? If vector, use MLP; If sequence, go with RNN or 1d CNN.

Can you please elaborate more?

Sure,  but I at least need to know the data type (i.e., the shape, dimensionality) :) I mean what is this "signal" you referring to? It is a sequence of features of shape (N, T, D)? Where N is the number of data samples, T the sequence length, and D the dimensionality of num. features-

Thank you for the reply, https://github.com/AMHD/Jamming-Detection-in-IoT-Wireless-Networks-An-Edge-AI-Based-Approach ...in this repo, in the dataset portion you can see the signal values (they have been recorded at a constant interval of 30 minutes) are in a 1D array form. What's the simplest deep learning appraoch that will fit? I'm trying to experiment with jammer signal & normal signal identiication through DL approaches but I want to start with simple approach. Thank you for your time.

Since the datasets are just a list of numbers, I think the simplest approach to be classification. Basically, you concatenate the three datasets into one while associating a label to each number: you should obtain something like (x, y=1=normal) or (x,y=0=jammed) for each entry/sample. Then you feed the x to the neural net classifier to predict the y. Let me know if this works. Also, remember to shuffle the data while training the neural net

Hi Luca, I was wondering would concatenating and shuffling be a good idea? because to my understanding, the list of numbers in one file is one complete signal so if I were to shuffle the numbers, the sequence would be interrupted as the values vary in some pattern. The rest I understand, it can be a multi-class classification problem, y=0 for normal, y=1 for a randomly jammed signal and y=2 for a constantly jammed signal / splitting into testing and training bit and so on. What do you think? I'll try the classification method and definitely let you know how it went.

Ok if, so you can also group the single numbers into consecutive chunks of size T, classifying a sequence of T of them each time. Doing so results in sequences of shape (B,T) or (B, T, 1). Then you can still apply MLP but also RNNs. But I suggest you to try the simplest thing first, then try with something more complex.

I see, that makes sense, I'll do the grouping approach definitely. I'll let you know how it goes or if I face another challenge
